# How to delete smaller multiple objects in my scene using Blender script?

Tags: python, blender, mesh

I am using Blender 2.8. I want to import an object into blender that is made up of a few pieces that aren't connected. So I want to split the object up and only export the largest of the pieces.

So lets say there are 3 pieces in one object, one big and two small. I'm able to turn this object into three objects, each containing one of the pieces. I would like to delete the two smaller objects and only keep the largest one. I'm thinking maybe to somehow find the surface area of the three different objects and only keep the largest while deleting all others? I'm pretty new at Blender.

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath='path/of/file.stl')
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
amount_of_pieces = len(context.selected_objects)

if amount_of_pieces > 1:
    highest_surface_area = 0

    #the rest is pseudocode
    for object in scene:
        if object.area > highest_surface_area:
            highest_surface_area = object.area
        else:
            bpy.ops.object.delete()

bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath='path/of/new/file.stl')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to write a code that works for this, however, it is very long and chaotic. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice on cleaning it up.

```
import bpy
import os
import bmesh


context = bpy.context

file = (r'path\to\file.stl')

bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath= file)
fileName = os.path.basename(file)[:-4].capitalize()
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
piece = len(context.selected_objects)
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

high = 0
if piece > 1:
    bpy.data.objects[fileName].select_set(True)
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
    area = sum(f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces)
    high = area
    bm.free()
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    for x in range (1, piece):
        name = fileName + '.00' + str(x)
        object = bpy.data.objects[name]
        context.view_layer.objects.active = object
        bpy.data.objects[name].select_set(True)
        obj = bpy.context.active_object
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
        newArea = sum(f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces)
        bm.free()
        if newArea > high:
            high = newArea
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        else:
            bpy.ops.object.delete()
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    if area != high:
        bpy.data.objects[fileName].select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.delete()


bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath= 'path/to/export/file.stl')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps would be :-

- import file
- break into multiple objects
- for safety, get a list of mesh objects
- list the surface area of each object
- get the max from the list of areas
- delete the not biggest objects
- export the largest
- cleanup

We don't need to use [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) to get the surface area, the normal mesh data includes [polygon.area](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.area).

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), we can get most steps into one line each.

```
import bpy

# import and separate
file = (r'path/of/file.stl')
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath= file)
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')

# list of mesh objects
mesh_objs = [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects
                if o.type == 'MESH']

# dict with surface area of each object
obj_areas = {o:sum([f.area for f in o.data.polygons])
                for o in mesh_objs}

# which is biggest
big_obj = max(obj_areas, key=obj_areas.get)

# select and delete not biggest
[o.select_set(o is not big_obj) for o in mesh_objs]
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)

#export
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath= 'path/of/new/file.stl')

# cleanup
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)
```